# Is it possible to chain streams in dart?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a document from firestore as stream, but before that I need to know which is the ID of that document, and that is stored in another level of the tree (this is the last document viewed), but this can change any time so this is another stream.

The db tree in firestore is like this:

```
user
    |__lastViewed: 'idtwo'
    |
    |__addresses
                |_idone
                |      |...
                |
                |_idtwo
                |      |...
                |
                |_idthree
                         |...
```

Is there any solution other than StreamBuilder?

Comment: Have you managed to get this working?